# OTA stock firmware zip

Tags: recovery-mode

I have a bricked TV Box MeCool HM8 and I need to restore it to factory settings
,unfortunately I have the stock firmwave in zip format and need to convert it in image format to be able to use an sd card for recovery.. Any help, advice , would be appreciated..thank you.
regards.
Guitsy

Comment: I thought you were able to load ZIP files from recovery menu. What makes you think you need an Image file?

Comment: I cannot get to the recovery menu ,the box is not responding ,just the dreaded red light is showing ..